# Separate values into columns

Tags: c#

I want to separate values into columns.
The 3 columns are: EmployeeId, Name, Salary.

I don´t want to use split method so I try this instead

```
  private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list1= new List<string>();
        List<string> list2= new List<string>();
        List<string> list3= new List<string>();



        var word= "";
        using (var rd = new StreamReader(@"C:\xxx.csv"))
        {
            while (!rd.EndOfStream)
            {

                var line = rd.ReadLine();
                for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (line[i] != Convert.ToChar(","))
                    {
                        word= word+ line[i];
                    }
                    if (line[i] == Convert.ToChar(","))
                    {
                        list1.Add(word);
                        word= "";
                    }
                    if (i == (line.Length - 1))
                    {
                        list3.Add(word);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Employee ID:");
        foreach (var num in list1)
            Console.WriteLine(num);

        Console.WriteLine("employeename:");
        foreach (var employeename in list2)
            Console.WriteLine(employeename);
        Console.WriteLine("Salary");
        foreach (var employeesalary in list3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(employeesalary);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
}
```

The column `employeeSalary` gets assigned correctly, however, `EmployeeName` column receives all values (wrong) and `EmployeeID` does not contain anything.
Can anyone help me to find the error?

Comment: How about using `IndexOf` and `SubString` string functions?

Comment: I need to do it with loops, there are no way like I doing it?

Comment: Also from your code, I don't see any place you are adding it `columna1` list.

Comment: No brecause I don´t know how can I do it, I dont know how to separate first values before first comma to add to column one like I do fine in column3 @HariPrasad

Comment: You're not adding anything to columna1 list, which explains why it's empty (Employee ID Column). Column 3 makes sense, and appears to work as intended. Column 2 is strange - per your code, it should work, unless I'm missing something... can you post a few lines of the csv file?

Comment: I upload it into my question @CoolBots

Comment: CSV is good; you're not resetting palabra once it's added to columna3 list

Comment: How can I do that? @CoolBots

Comment: I posted an answer with working code, and commented my additions for your review.

Comment: What's wrong with `.Split(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working version of your code. I added some comments, removed the unnecessary Convert.ToChar calls, and added curly braces around prints, just as general code cleanup. Notice the else-if within the loop as well, as some of the situations are mutually exclusive. My answer is inline with my comments on your original post.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var employeeIDs = new List<string>();
        var employeeNames = new List<string>();
        var employeeSalaries = new List<string>();


        var tmp = "";
        using (var rd = new StreamReader(@"values.csv"))
        {
            while (!rd.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = rd.ReadLine();
                bool isFirstColumn = true;          //Indicates we are looking for first column value at this time

                for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (line[i] != ',')
                    {
                        tmp = tmp + line[i];
                    }
                    else if (line[i] == ',')
                    {
                        if (isFirstColumn)
                        {
                            //This is the ID, because isFirstColumn is still set to true
                            employeeIDs.Add(tmp);
                            isFirstColumn = false;      //Next "," separates the name
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //This is the name, because isFirstColumn is now false
                            employeeNames.Add(tmp);
                        }

                        tmp = "";
                    }

                    if (i == (line.Length - 1))
                    {
                        employeeSalaries.Add(tmp);
                        tmp = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Employee ID:");
        foreach (var num in employeeIDs)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(num);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("name:");
        foreach (var name in employeeNames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Salary");
        foreach (var salary in employeeSalaries)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(salary);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: I'm going to guess by that response that my code worked for you, and that it is likely homework... I recommend you review the code, and compare to your version to understand the differences, for your own benefit. If you would kindly mark my answer as accepted, I'd appreciate it. In terms of changing variables, I updated my answer w/o your variable names.

Comment: These are any Way to order values for descending?

Comment: Since you're storing the data in 3 separate lists, not an easy way. In general, check out [sorting algorithms](http://sorting-algorithms.com/)

Comment: And if I only want to sort salary column?

Comment: Easiest way is using LINQ extensions and lambda; otherwise, refer to a simple sorting algorithm, like Bubble Sort (it's a naive sort, but works fine for this task). The LINQ/lambda solution: change the output for salaries to read `foreach(var salary in employeeSalaries.OrderByDescending(v => v))`

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked not to use `.Split(...)`, but why not? Your code could look like this:

```
string[][] data =
    File
        .ReadAllLines(@"C:\xxx.csv")
        .Select(line => line.Split(','))
        .ToArray();

List<string> list1 = data.Select(line => line[0]).ToList();
List<string> list2 = data.Select(line => line[1]).ToList();
List<string> list3 = data.Select(line => line[2]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I could quickly thin of this solution if I asked to do this with simple loops and not using any string functions.

Use this logic inside while loop, probably you might want to move `List` declaration to before while.

```
bool firstcolumn= false, secondcolumn = false, thirdcolumn= false;

System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
List<string> list3 = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
{
    if(line[i] != ',' && i != line.Length -1) 
    {
        sb.Append(line[i]);
        continue;
    }

    if(!firstcolumn)
    {
        firstcolumn = true;
        list1.Add(sb.ToString());

    }
    else if(!secondcolumn)
    {
        secondcolumn = true;
        list2.Add(sb.ToString());

    }
    else
    {
        thirdcolumn = true;
        list3.Add(sb.ToString());
    }

    sb.Clear();     
}
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QmzVAz)

Comment: What is stopping? if you've valid string with 2 `,` it should work. Did you check the demo?